# Check and validate the phone number and replace if it's in the wrong format

Tags: validation

I want to validate the phone number field and it should accept the valid phone number entries only.

e.g:

1. if I enter phone number as 337485552599 
       it should automatically replace the phone number as 07485552599
2. if I enter phone number as 00337485552599 
       it should automatically replace the phone number as 07485552599

Comment: you can use regex for it and can format the number as you wish.

Comment: @Tushar: Can you please post the regex code if you have so it would be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a trigger, but there are several considerations based on the problem you've described...

**Validation**

If you know exactly how many digits **all** your phone numbers will be then this isn't a problem, you simply need to check for the right number of characters, but I know of several countries (France included, which by the +33 dialling code is where I am guessing you are from) whose phone numbers can have a varying number of digits. In the UK, both 9 and 10 digit (excluding prefixes) are valid, which means unless you are checking against a database you may run into some problems.

**Replacement**

Replacing parts of the phone number sting is trivial as long as you know exactly which characters to replace, but as described above if the number is not *n* digits long, you will have some issues.

**Solution**

If you just want the two particular cases you gave in your question to be covered, the following code will suffice:

```
trigger PhoneReplace on Account (before insert) {

    for (Account a : trigger.New) {

        if (!String.IsBlank(a.Phone)) {
            if (a.Phone.startsWith('0033')) {
                a.Phone = '0' + a.Phone.right(a.Phone.length() - 4);
            } else if (a.Phone.startsWith('33')) {
                a.Phone = '0' + a.Phone.right(a.Phone.length() - 2);
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friends for your valuable solutions. Could you please tell me how would I elaborate the above trigger if I need to check the phone length is 10 digit only followed by 0? I also need to replace '+' with 0(if phone number start with +)  and '+91' with 0. (if phone number start with + followed by country code)

Comment: To get rid of special characters such as '+', you can use the `replace(target, replacement)` method using '+' as the target. I would advise using an empty string (**''**) as the replacement value, as there is more that can go wrong the more characters you individually replace. Check out the [documentation for String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) for more info.